# Rename keys and summarize values

Tags: php, arrays

I would appreciate some help with this, actually i have code ready but its messy and its done with 2 foreach loops, i was wondering if it can be done in more elegant way. This is my array construct:

```
$result = Array([200001079412] => Array
                                  (
                                   [0] => INITAMNT:95.39,
                                   [1] => PAYAMNT:95.39,
                                   [2] => WRTOFFAMNT:0.00,
                                   [3] => OPENAMNT:0.00,
                                   [4] => INVAMNT:95.39,
                                   [5] => INITAMNT:91.08,
                                   [6] => PAYAMNT:91.08,
                                   [7] => WRTOFFAMNT:0.00,
                                   [8] => OPENAMNT:0.00,
                                   [9] => INVAMNT:91.08,
                                   [10] => INITAMNT:94.85,
                                   [11] => PAYAMNT:94.85,
                                   [12] => WRTOFFAMNT:0.00,
                                   [13] => OPENAMNT:0.00,
                                   [14] => INVAMNT:94.85,
                                  )

                 [200001672956] => Array
                                  (
                                   [0] => INITAMNT:127.40,
                                   [1] => PAYAMNT:127.40,
                                   [2] => WRTOFFAMNT:0.00,
                                   [3] => OPENAMNT:0.00,
                                   [4] => INVAMNT:704.40,
                                   )
```

I would like to: in 2nd level of array, replace keys with character part of the values, and summarize all values with same key

Here, ive replaced keys with character part of the values:

```
$arr_new = array();                                     
foreach($result as $key => $arr) {
   foreach($arr as $key1 => $val) {
     $str = explode(":", $val);
     $arr_new[$key][$str[0]][$key1] = $str[1];
   }
}
```

And here ive summarized all values with same key category:

```
foreach ($arr_new as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($val as $k1 => $v1) {
         $val[$key][$k1] = array_sum($v1);
     }
}
```

Heres my array output:

```
Array
(
[INITAMNT] => Array
    (
        [0] => 95.39,
        [5] => 91.08,
        [10] => 94.85,
    )

[PAYAMNT] => Array
    (
        [1] => 95.39,
        [6] => 91.08,
        [11] => 94.85,
    )

[WRTOFFAMNT] => Array
    (
        [2] => 0.00,
        [7] => 0.00,
        [12] => 0.00,
    )

[OPENAMNT] => Array
    (
        [3] => 0.00,
        [8] => 0.00,
        [13] => 0.00,
    )

[INVAMNT] => Array
    (
        [4] => 95.39,
        [9] => 91.08,
        [14] => 94.85,
    )

[200001079412] => Array
    (
        [INITAMNT] => 281.32
        [PAYAMNT] => 281.32
        [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
        [OPENAMNT] => 0
        [INVAMNT] => 281.32
    )

)
Array
(
[INITAMNT] => Array
    (
        [0] => 127.40,
    )

[PAYAMNT] => Array
    (
        [1] => 127.40,
    )

[WRTOFFAMNT] => Array
    (
        [2] => 0.00,
    )

[OPENAMNT] => Array
    (
        [3] => 0.00,
    )

[INVAMNT] => Array
    (
        [4] => 704.40,
    )

[200001672956] => Array
    (
        [INITAMNT] => 127.4
        [PAYAMNT] => 127.4
        [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
        [OPENAMNT] => 0
        [INVAMNT] => 704.4
    )
```

)

I only need last part of the array, like:

```
Array ([200001079412] => Array
                        (
                         [INITAMNT] => 281.32
                         [PAYAMNT] => 281.32
                         [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
                         [OPENAMNT] => 0
                         [INVAMNT] => 281.32
                        )
       [200001672956] => Array
                        (
                         [INITAMNT] => 127.4
                         [PAYAMNT] => 127.4
                         [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
                         [OPENAMNT] => 0
                         [INVAMNT] => 704.4
                         )
 )
```

Can it be done in more concise and easyer approach, with only one foreach loop ? Thx.

Comment: Off topic, but I like you profile image ;)

Comment: Well, thx for teh observation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is foreach loop,

```
$arr_new = [];
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    array_walk($value, function($val) use(&$arr_new,$key){
        list($k,$v) = explode(":",$val);
        $arr_new[$key][$k] = ($arr_new[$key][$k] ?? 0) + $v;
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/dYorj)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [200001079412] => Array
        (
            [INITAMNT] => 281.32
            [PAYAMNT] => 281.32
            [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
            [OPENAMNT] => 0
            [INVAMNT] => 281.32
        )

    [200001672956] => Array
        (
            [INITAMNT] => 127.4
            [PAYAMNT] => 127.4
            [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
            [OPENAMNT] => 0
            [INVAMNT] => 704.4
        )

)
```

Comment: You're iterating over `$value` twice by doing the `array_map` and then the `foreach`...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I made changes. I still think of possible optimization.

Comment: One thing, output is fine, but there is Notice warning: A non well formed numeric value encountered in last line of foreach, guessing something needs integer conversion

Comment: Its ok, ive turned notices off.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge your code into one foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        list ($k, $v) = explode(':', $val);
        $newarr[$key][$k] = ($newarr[$key][$k] ?? 0) + $v;
    }
}
print_r($newarr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [200001079412] => Array
        (
            [INITAMNT] => 281.32
            [PAYAMNT] => 281.32
            [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
            [OPENAMNT] => 0
            [INVAMNT] => 281.32
        )
    [200001672956] => Array
        (
            [INITAMNT] => 127.4
            [PAYAMNT] => 127.4
            [WRTOFFAMNT] => 0
            [OPENAMNT] => 0
            [INVAMNT] => 704.4
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/i6hSO)

Comment: Better approach+!1

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this as

```
 $r = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v){
 foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
    $key   = substr($v1, 0, strpos($v1, ':'));
    $value = substr($v1, strpos($v1, ':')+1, strlen($v1));
    isset($r[$k][$key]) ? ($r[$k][$key] += $value) : ($r[$k][$key] = $value);
  }
}
```

Live example :- https://3v4l.org/p6ZCK